# Rails Routing question

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I'm not very familiar with routing, but here is my dilemma:

I have a `photos` controller with the usual `show`, `edit`, etc. views. I am trying to build a view to moderate `photos`. I have a `moderate.html.erb` view under my `photos` views. I have also defined `moderate` method in my `photos_controller`. If I try to access this view like `/photos/moderate` I get `Couldn't find Photo with ID=moderate`.

Am I building this the correct way, or does `moderate` need to have its own separate controller and view? Seems silly to me for that to be the case. Is this just something I need to configure in my routes?

**UPDATE:**
I've added this to my routes:

```
resources :photos do
  resources :comments
  collection do
    get 'moderate'
  end
end
```

Still getting the same `Couldn't find Photo with ID=moderate` message when I go to `/photos/moderate`...

**UPDATE:**

Crap! Just figured out the problem. I had a before_filter running that needed to ignore the moderate action... It's now working fine. Sorry for the trouble.

Comment: could sound like a funny question but the `authorize_and_load` method from cancan could lead this kind of failures

Comment: Thanks to your update I now understad much better. It was a tricky trap like the cancan's :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a further restful action. Take a look at the [docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#adding-more-restful-actions)

Comment: Thanks @lucpaette. That seems to address my objective, but I've modified my routes (see update above) and I'm still getting the same error. Any thoughts?

Comment: Run rake routes in your app dir. It will give you all the defined routes

Comment: Interesting. This is in there: moderate_photos GET    /photos/moderate(.:format)...

Comment: O but what do you need to do? I mean, you need a method for _a_ resource or for a _collection_? The correct definition of the routes depends on that.

Comment: Hm, I'm not sure. I am unfamiliar with collections apart from the ror.org doc. The purpose of the "moderate" page is just type of index for photos. Rather than showing all approved photos, it would show only photos that have not yet been approved.

Answer (score 0):

So you're trying to split out the concern of being able to edit and view photos?

If you wanted to keep your actions RESTful, you could create a "moderate" namespace and put all the actions that require authentication for photos in that namespace.

For instance,

```
#routes.rb
namespace :moderate do
   resources :photos # will create paths like '/moderate/photos/', '/moderate/photos/1'
end

#controllers/moderate/photos_controller.rb
class Moderate::PhotosController < ActionController

  before_filter :authorize_moderator!

  #your standard restful actions like 'index', 'show', 'edit, 'update' would go in here.
end
```